# How to use ethereum on decentralized exchanges in the US?

Tags: security, decentralized-exchange

See https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/145yka4/comment/jnoduy1/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

> Dex's don't deal with Fiat directly, you always need a cex to buy your
> stable coins and to sell.

Let's say you are in the US

What would be the choices for decentralized exchanges?

What are the differences?

Is the comment correct that you still have to use centralized exchanges to enter and leave via FIAT currency?

Someone posted https://www.securities.io/buy-dydx/

> Dydx is a different type of decentralized exchange that is built on
> the Starkware layer 2 network. Unlike automated market makers such as
> Uniswap or SushiSwap it features an order book architecture. The
> network also offers a staking mechanism to earn rewards for
> contributing to liquidity and safety. Users who participate can trade
> in spot, perpetual futures, and margin markets on multiple trading
> pairs.

Is that true? I do not even think spot markets exist on dydx?

I'm glad people are asking questions and these facts are being discussed. Why should Jamie be the secret holder? I'm fairly sure Jamie is not happy that "decentralize" exists. But of course they will find a way to profit.

It's like the old saying. Take all the money/property/tokens/etc in the world and re-distribute it equally. In a few months, it would be back in the original holders hands because that mostly what they focus on.

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

◉_◉